# How would a 'dll missing' error be thrown when a specific web page is loaded?

Tags: dll, sandbox, error-logging

I'm building a website and am working with a conversion plugin. The conversion works perfectly for me as I've tested the dependencies on my localhost, but when I moved it to my server and installed it and visit the page from a separate computer without those dependencies, I get this error:

```
The program can't start because MSVCP120.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I know how to fix the issue, but I'm curious as to how a conversion plugin installed on a Linux server was able to throw this error as a System Error popup on my Windows machine, rather than just fail in the sandboxed browser.

To reiterate, I go to www.example.com/page and upon loading this exception is thrown on my Windows system.

Comment: probably because the component throwing the error is in windows or other low level API code the browser is calling, so its not the page itself thats crashing, just the implementation of some code in the page that is crashing your browsers dependencies. Javascript or CGI code in a page on a linux system addresses the linux system API one way, but that same line of javascript is rendered by the windows browser using differant API calls to do the same thing, and in the process, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The server was referencing 'localhost', but my computer was interpreting localhost through XAMPP and trying to locate the resources on my running local server rather than through the remote server, which explains why the error was outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `msvcp120.dll` file is part of the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784). Since you created your plugin using Visual Studio 2013, this package is a requirement, unless you chose to statically link it.

I very much doubt your Linux server is ever executing that plugin of yours. It’s a Windows DLL after all.

If you want further details on why this happens, you’ll first have to provide additional information in that plugin of yours and how exactly it’s used/embedded in a web page.